# Noob Guidance on a Parallel Task Workflow (without Visual Studio)

Tags: sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-workflow

This is going to be my first workflow, and I could use a little guidance.

I have a list I'm using for requests when a user needs their profile changed (eg: change of office location). The change has to be done in AD, PeopleSoft, and another database. Right now, I have it set up so requesters submit an item to a list, and Alerts go out to the different people responsible for making the updates in AD, PeopleSoft, etc. However, there has been enough frustration with missed emails and the like that I've been asked to track via workflow.

So essentially, I need to track a request that goes out to multiple users who will then need to confirm that the task has been completed. I found !(http://officeimg.vo.msecnd.net/en-us/files/989/238/ZA102615287.jpg), which is a very good representation of what I want to do, but does a very confusing job of explaining how to do it: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-help/all-about-approval-workflows-HA102771433.aspx

Can someone point me to the workflow type that I need and the steps to implement? OOB/SPDesigner please, I don't have VS on my machine.

Thanks,

Scott

Answer (score 0):

I will start by saying that implementing parallel tasks in a single workflow is hard.

What you can do is customise the OOB approval workflow (the one mentioned in the article) to suit your needs. This will give you an insight on how Sharepoint Workflows work and are designed.

It will look confusing at start (very confusing) since like i said is a complex workflow to setup,  until you start to understand how it works.

make sure you make a copy of the approval workflow before modifying it so you can still use it if needed.